# get value from custom attribute in editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, editortemplates

at the moment I have this:

in the ViewModel:

```
[MyCustom(Foo = 23)]
public int CountryId { get; set; }
```

in the Editor template:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("", Model) %>
```

how can I get the value (Foo=23) from my custom attribute (MyCustom) into the editor template ?

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2010/06/12/asp-net-mvc-2-auto-complete-textbox-custom-view-model-attribute-amp-editortemplate.aspx) that you might find useful.

Answer (score 10):

In Editor Template you can get the value of custom attribute as below.

```
@model int

@{       
    var CustomAttributes = (ViewData.ModelMetadata).ContainerType.GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MvcApplication7.Models.MyCustomAttribute), false);
    if (CustomAttributes.Length > 0)
    {
        MvcApplication7.Models.MyCustomAttribute CustomAttribute = CustomAttributes[0] as MvcApplication7.Models.MyCustomAttribute;

        //That is how you get the value of foo. You can use it as per need of the editor template.
        @CustomAttribute.Foo   
    }
}
```